# How do I test for a maximum tie across multiple columns in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find the max value and its column ID across 25 columns in my Pandas dataframe, and if there's a two-way or three-way tie for first, print "tie" in one new column and the max (tied) value in another.

This is the output I'm trying to achieve:

| a | b | c | max_value | max_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 3 | tie |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | a |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 3 | c |

I originally used the simple combination of:

```
df["max_id"] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
df["max_value"] = df.max(axis=1)
```

However this doesn't behave how I would like when handling ties, only returning the first of the max values.

I have tried a few routes to achieve my goal in Pandas. In my attempt below my aim was to first identify the ties, but had no luck with that either:

```
df["max_id"] = df.apply(lambda x: "tie" if x.max() == df.iloc[int(x.name)]["max_value"] else "False", axis=1 )
```

The result was the whole column filled with "tie".

I also went down the route of creating a for loop from a solution I found online designed for 3 set values, however I am not great with loops yet and kept running into brick walls. This was the online solution I have been trying to adapt for my larger dataset:

```
def max_num(a, b, c):
    if a > b and a > c:
        return a
    elif b > a and b > c:
        return b
    elif c > a and c > b:
        return c
    else:
        return “It’s a tie!”
```

Ideally wanted to avoid loops and stick with Pandas though as it's seeming like it would be quite a complicated loop.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with `np.where`

```
df['max_id'] = np.where(df.eq(df.max(1),0).sum(1)>1,'tie',df.idxmax(1))
df['max_value'] = df.max(1)

df
Out[108]: 
   a  b  c max_id  max_value
0  1  3  3    tie          3
1  3  2  2      a          3
2  1  2  3      c          3
```